# How to get the heart rate from raw ECG data in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, medical, heartbeat

I would like to know whether there is a open source code in objective C to get heart rate from ECG raw data. Here is a sample ECG raw data values I am getting from ECG lead 1:

```
ECG1Sample1: 1743
2016-06-29 16:17:12.306 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 2197
2016-06-29 16:17:12.306 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1925
2016-06-29 16:17:12.344 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1814
2016-06-29 16:17:12.345 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1780
2016-06-29 16:17:12.360 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1781
2016-06-29 16:17:12.361 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1791
2016-06-29 16:17:12.420 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1785
2016-06-29 16:17:12.421 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1785
2016-06-29 16:17:12.422 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1796
2016-06-29 16:17:12.468 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1785
2016-06-29 16:17:12.469 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1785
2016-06-29 16:17:12.480 BedLocator[1007:209212] ECG1Sample1: 1746
```

How to get the heart rate?

Comment: From where are coming theses values? I'm wondering if they are respecting some BLE protocols (https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/pages/health-device-profile.aspx), or others... Don't you have a documentation?

Comment: Hi @Larme. Yes there are respecting BLE protocols. Here is the code where these values are coming from.                                                                ---if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FFF4"]]) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.0001f];
        NSData *data = characteristic.value;

Comment: What your print is the `NSData` object?

Comment: Look at Apple's Sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Listings/HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011322-HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4 Rest of the doc: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml